# Rails: including concern in controller results in action 'index' could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Using rails as an API (but ApplicationController < ActionController::Base)

Entries controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    include current_user_concern
    def index
        @entries = Entry.where(user_id: @current_user.id)
        # if(params[:tag])
        #   @entries = @entries.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        # end
        render json: @entries
    end
```

current_user_concern:

```
module CurrentUserConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_current_user
  end

  def set_current_user
    puts "in currentUserConcern set_current_user"
    puts session[:user_id]
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

With the current code I get error `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for EntriesController):` though the user_id does get printed to bash console.

If I remove the line `include current_user_concern` from entries_controller, on execution it enters index (but as expected errors at @current_user.id which would have been defined in current_user_concern)

It appears from the bash console log that perhaps index is being called before the concern?

```
Started GET "/entries" for ::1 at 2020-01-11 16:46:02 +0800
Started GET "/logged_in" for ::1 at 2020-01-11 16:46:02 +0800

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'index' could not be found for EntriesController):

actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:259:in `context'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:253:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
Processing by SessionsController#logged_in as HTML
in currentUserConcern set_current_user
3

  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_user_concern.rb:13:in `set_current_user'
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms | Allocations: 18228)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `include CurrentUserConcern` instead of `include current_user_concern`

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentUserConcern
end
```